# VMware Virtual Machine (Ubuntu) Move Image to Machine

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-fusion, v2p

I have a Ubuntu Server 8.04 VM set up with VMware. Is there any way to take this image and make it not a virtual machine. i.e. put it on a real machine.

If there is absolutely no way to do it, what are some tips/tools/tricks to make the transition as easy as possible. There's tons of pre-release software that needs an absurdly specific configuration to run, and the documentation for installing it is essentially non-existant.

Also, just to complicate things, VMware is running on a Mac Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you could use an imaging software such as Ghost or Acronis to create an image to be deployed on physical hardware. You would just need to install the drivers...

Comment: Or you can use [PartImage](http://www.partimage.org/) or [FSArchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/), which is open source and available on the [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/).  And unless you have hardware that's not supported by default, there probably is no need to install drivers.

Answer (score 0):

There's a VMWare technical note on this here: [V2PTechNote.fm](http://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/doc/V2P_TechNote.pdf)

I haven't tried it, so I don't know how smoothly it works.

The manual has plenty of information on importing from physical and virtual machines into VMs, but not much on getting them out again! Makes sense I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://techokarma.blogspot.com/2008/10/v2p-virtual-to-physical-for-virtualbox.html) requires Virtualbox, so you will have to install it and convert the virtual machine, but it seems pretty straight forward. Convert disk to RAW, then dd image onto the harddrive you will use in your physical box.